# WebAPI2 Json.Net Required property not adding ModelState Error properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
public class Value
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public int Num { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}        

public Value Post(Value value)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Bad request
    }
    return value;
}
```

I am trying to enforce that all values are specified in a post request to a web api. In the Value model above, when the Num property is omitted:

```
 {"Id": "abc", "Name":"John"}
```

it adds an error to the model state indicating its absence. However, when the Id property is omitted:

```
 {"Num" : 3, "Name" : "John"}
```

unexpectedly, no model state error is added, and the model is considered valid.

When I manually Deserialize the model with `JsonConvert.Deserialize` it throws a serialization exception in both cases indicating that the property is missing. Why does it appear to add model state errors when a value type (int) is not present correctly, but not when a reference type (string) is missing from the request body? How can I include those in the model state errors?

Note: It is not enough to put a `[Required]` attribute on the Id property. I want to allow a null or empty string value to be posted, as long as it is included in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
[DataMember]
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.AllowNull)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```